# NestJs - How to unit test a DTO?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am asking you for help. I have created a DTO that looks like it (this is a smaller version) :

```
export class OfImportDto {

    @IsString({
        message: "should be a valid product code"
    })
    productCode: string;

    @IsString({
        message: "Enter the proper product description"
    })
    productDescription: string;

    @IsDateString({
        message: "should be a valid date format, for example : 2017-06-07T14:34:08+04:00"
    })
    manufacturingDate : Date

    @IsInt({
        message: "should be a valid planned quantity number"
    })
    @IsPositive()
    plannedQuantity: number;
```

the thing is that i am asking to test that, with a unit test and not a E2E test. And I Don't know how to do that. For instance, I would like to unit test 
1/ if my product code is well a string, a string should be created, if not, throw my exception
2/ if my product description is well a string, a string should be created, if not, throw my exception
...
and so on.

So, can I made a spec.ts file to test that? If yes, how?
If not, is it better to test it within the service.spec.ts? If so, how?

Thank you very much, any help would be very helpful :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should create a separate DTO specific file like `of-import.dto.spec.ts` for unit tests of your DTOs. Let's see how to test a DTO in Nest.js step by step.

---

### TLDR: Your DTO's unit test

To understand it line by line, continue reading:

```
it('should throw when the planned quantity is a negative number.', async () => {
  const importInfo = { productCode: 4567, plannedQuanity: -10 }
  const ofImportDto = plainToInstance(OfImportDto, importInfo)
  const errors = await validate(ofImportDto)
  expect(errors.length).not.toBe(0)
  expect(stringified(errors)).toContain(`Planned Quantity must be a positive number.`)
}
```

---

### Create a plain object to test

The following is an object that you would like to test for validation:

```
const importInfo = { productCode: 4567, plannedQuanity: -10 }
```

If your test object has nested objects or it's too big, you can skip those complex properties. We'll see how to deal with that.

---

### Convert the test object to the type of DTO

Use `plainToinstace()` function from the `class-transformer` package:

```
const ofImportDto = plainToInstance(OfImportDto, importInfo)
```

This will turn your plain test object to the object of the type of your DTO, that is, `OfImportDto`.

If you have any transformations in your DTO, like trimming spaces of the values of properties, they are applied at this point. If you just intend to test the transformations, you can assert now, you don't have to call the following `validate()` function for testing transformations.

---

### Emulate the validation

Use the `validate()` function from the `class-validator` package:

```
const errors = await validate(ofImportDto)
```

If you skipped some properties while creating the test object, you can deal with that like the following:

```
const errors = await validate(ofImportDto, { skipMissingProperties: true })
```

Now the validation will ignore the missing properties.

---

### Assert the errors

Assert that the `errors` array is not empty and it contains your custom error message:

```
expect(errors.length).not.toBe(0)
expect(stringified(errors)).toContain(`Planned Quantity must be a positive number.`)
```

Here `stringified()` is a helper function to convert the `errors` object to a JSON string, so we can search if it contains our custom error message:

```
export function stringified(errors: ValidationError[]): string {
  return JSON.stringify(errors)
}
```

---

That's it! Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

It would be possible to create a `OfImportDTO.spec.ts` file (or whatever your original file is called), but the thing is, there isn't any logic here to test. The closest thing you could do is create an instance of a `Validator` from `class-validator` and then instantiate an instance of the `OfImportDto` and then check that the class passes validation. If you add logic to it (e.g. getters and setters with specific functions) then it could make sense for unit testing, but otherwise, this is basically an interface being called a class so it exists at runtime for `class-validator`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too. Would it be possible to test it via my service.spec.ts? Because there is logic inside, perhaps calling a mock of the DTO and do some testing would work?

Comment: What kind of logic, because in your code snippet above it's just definition of fields along with decorators. What are you trying to test with this?

Comment: I still don't see anything to test with regards to the DTO file. Testing services and controllers is another thing, but testing the DTO file doesn't make much sense in this case

Comment: What i want is to be sure that the data from dto are ok. I wonder if i can check every field within the service test. For example : if the product code is not a string, reject it. Based on the dto and not the entity. Would it be possible?

Comment: Like I said in my answer, you could always use an instance of the `Validator` from `class-validator` an ensure your decorators provide the enforcement you expect them to. That's why Nest has the `pipe` enhancer: for data validation and transformation. But otherwise, running automated tests against a DTO file is not really useful.

Comment: Ok i'll do it this way. Thank you :)